# How to resolve external dependencies defined in a Grails plugin in a Grails 2.2.x application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I asked this question on the Grails user list but didn’t get a response, so I’ll rephrase it here. I’m the author of a Grails plugin (https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-atmosphere-meteor), which has two external dependencies defined in BuildConfig.groovy.

When the plugin is installed in a new Grails 2.2.x application, the external dependencies are not resolved in the app. When running it I get "unable to resolve class" errors on the import statements for the classes defined in the plugin’s dependencies.

A plugin user should be able to insert the plugin dependency in an app’s BuildConfig.groovy and have the two external dependencies resolved automatically. grails.project.dependency.resolution.legacyResolve should be the default value of false.

Additionally, I want to test the plugin using https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-plugin-test-script before publishing it to the Grails plugin portal. I have an artifactory repo running on localhost (defined as localPluginReleases in the plugin's BuildConfig.groovy).

The plugin is built using Grails 2.2.3 and uses release plugin version 2.2.1. I've tried varying combinations of the below without success:

```
grails clean 
grails compile 
grails maven-install 
grails generate-pom 
grails package-plugin
grails publish-plugin --noScm --repository=localPluginReleases 
grails maven-deploy --repository=localPluginReleases
```

What is the correct step-by-step to get this working?

Comment: I use `grails maven-install` and load my plugin from maven local (`~/.m2/`) repository

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work for a plugin published on the Grails portal although it'd work for testing before publishing.